# How to call a parallelized script from command prompt?

Tags: r, doparallel

I'm running into this issue and I for the life of me can't figure out how to solve it.

Quick summary before example:

I have several hundred data sets from which I want create reports on everyday. In order to do this efficiently, I parallelized the process with `doParallel`. From within RStudio, the process works fine, but when I try to make the process automatic via Task Scheduler on windows, I can't seem to get it to work.

The process within RStudio is:

I call a script that sources all of my other scripts, each individual script has a header section that performs the appropriate package import, so for instance it would look like:

```
get_files <- function(){
  get_files.create_path() -> path
  for(file in path){
   if(!(file.info(paste0(path, file))[['isdir']])){
    source(paste0(path, file))
   }
  }
}

get_files.create_path <- function(){
   return(<path to directory>)
}

#self call
get_files()
```

This would be simply "Source on saved" and brings in everything I need into the `.GlobalEnv`.

From there, I could simply type: `parallel_report()` which calls a script that sources another script that houses the parallelization of the report generations. There was an issue awhile back with simply calling the parallelization directly (I wonder if this is related?) and so I had to make the `doParallel` script a non-function housing script and thus couldn't be brought in with the `get_files` script which would start the report generation every time I brought everything in. Thus, I had to include it in its own script and save it elsewhere to be called when necessary. The `parallel_report()` function would simply be:

```
parallel_report <- function(){
  source(<path to script>)
}
```

Then the script that is sourced is the real parallelization script, and would look something like:

```
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl = (parallel::detectCores() - 1))
foreach(name = report.list$names,
        .packages = c('tidyverse', 'knitr', 'lubridate', 'stringr', 'rmarkdown'),
        .export = c('generate_report'),
        .errorhandling = 'remove') %dopar% {
  tryCatch(expr = {
    generate_report(name)
  }, error = function(e){
    error_handler(error = e, caller = paste0("generate report for ", name,  " from parallel"), line = 28)
  })
}
doParallel::stopImplicitCluster()
```

The `generate_report` function is simply an .Rmd and `render()` caller:

```
generate_report <- function(<arguments>){
 #stuff
 generate_report.render(<arguments>)
 #stuff 
}  

generate_report.render <- function(<arguments>){
   rmarkdown::render(
    paste0(data.information@location, 'report_generator.Rmd'),
    params = list(
      name = name,
      date = date,
      thoughts = thoughts, 
      auto = auto),
    output_file = paste0(str_to_upper(stock), '_report_', str_remove_all(date, '-'))
  )
}
```

So to recap, in RStudio I would simply perform the following:

1 - Source save the script to bring everything

2 - type `parallel_report`

2.a - this calls directly the `doParallization` of `generate_report`

2.b - `generate_report` calls an `.Rmd` file that houses the required function calling and whatnot to produce the reports

And the process starts and successfully completes without a hitch.

In order to make the situation automatic via the Task Scheduler, I made a script that the Task Scheduler can call, named `automatic_caller`:

```
source(<path to the get_files script>) # this brings in all the scripts and data into the global, just 
# as if it were being done manually
tryCatch(
  expr = {
    parallel_report()
  }, error = function(e){
     error_handler(error = e, caller = "parallel_report from automatic_callng", line = 39)
})
```

The `error_handler` function is just an in-house script used to log errors throughout.

So then on the Task Schedule's tasks I have the `Rscript.exe` called and then the `automatic_caller` after that. Everything within the `automatic_caller` function works *except for* the report generation.
The process completes almost automatically, and the only output I get is an error:

`"pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available)."`

But `rmarkdown` is within the `.export` call of the `doParallel` *and* it is in the scripts that use it explicitly, *and* in the actual `generate_report` it is called directly via `rmarkdown::render()`.

So - I am at a complete loss.

Thoughts and suggestions would be completely appreciated.

Comment: The error you get about "pandoc [...] is required and was not found" sounds like Rscript.exe cannot find where the pandoc.exe program lives on your computer. Have you tried running the program at the command prompt without the Task Scheduler? If you run the script in base R GUI outside of RStudio, does it work? Most likely you'll need to set your PATH environment variable for the Task Scheduler. I think RStudio has it's own version of pandoc it uses when you run it. You can check the value of `rmarkdown::find_pandoc()` to see the path. Your scheduled task needs to find that same path.

Comment: Please don't edit your post to include an answer. You can submit your own answer to your question below as a proper answer. This way the question will appear as answered and other people can vote on the solution or offer alternatives.

Comment: Apologies, doing that now.

Comment: MrFlick you’re completely right! Running the scripts feom command promot gave me the same errors. Once I realized what pandoc was, I first tried setting a PATH pointer to RStudio’s pandoc.exe and it still didn’t work so I just downloaded the binaries for pandoc which worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So pandoc is apprently an executable that helps convert files from one extension to another. RStudio comes with its own pandoc executable so when running the scripts from RStudio, it knew where to point when pandoc is required.

From the command prompt, the system did not know to look inside of RStudio, so simply downloading pandoc as a standalone executable gives the system the proper pointer.

Downloded pandoc and everything works fine.